error de programacion cmath (error)no es un miembro de global space)
Estoy haciendo un trabajo en FLTK donde se desarrollo el codigo en Linux en GNU NANO en el cual no me dio problema, entonces lo ando probando en Window utilizando VisualStudioCommunity por lo cual tuve que hacer la instalacion de FLTK en windows, ahora ya que tengo el codigo puesto y quiero compilarlo me sale que cmath tiene 125 errores donde no reconoce su propio codigo (Ej."powf" no es un miembro de global namespace y no se encontro el identificador). Esto es un problema ya que el codigo me marca por obvias razones Error C1003. Desconozco si cmath tiene algun problema pero acabo recientemente de reparar el Visual Studio Community por eso mismo
#include <Fl.H>
#include <FL_Window.H>
#include <FL_Box.H>
#include <FL_Button.H>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void cambiar_hora(Fl_Box* box);
void cambiar_color(Fl_Box* box);

void cambiar_hora(Fl_Widget* widget, void* data) {
    Fl_Box* box = (Fl_Box*)data;
    time_t t = time(nullptr);
    struct tm* tm = localtime(&t);
    char hora[9];
    strftime(hora, sizeof(hora), "%H:%M:%S", tm);
    box->label(hora);
    box->labelsize(48);
    cambiar_color(box);
    box->redraw();
}

void cambiar_color(Fl_Box* box) {
    int r = rand() % 256;
    int g = rand() % 256;
    int b = rand() % 256;
    box->labelcolor(fl_rgb_color(r, g, b));
}

int main() {
    Fl_Window* window = new Fl_Window(800, 600, "Reloj Cambiante");
    window->color(FL_WHITE);
    Fl_Box* box = new Fl_Box(200, 200, 400, 100, "00:00:00");
    box->labelsize(48);
    box->labelcolor(FL_YELLOW);
    box->color(FL_BLUE);
    Fl_Button* button = new Fl_Button(350, 400, 100, 30, "Actualizar Hora");
    button->callback(cambiar_hora, box);
    window->end();
    window->show();
    return Fl::run();
}


Por cierto el trabajo es un reloj :)

La cabecera cmath es de la librería estándar de C++ y declara sus funciones en el espacio std. math.h es parte de la librería estándar de C y las declara en el espacio global.
Es decir, tienes que escribir std:: antes del nombre de cada función matemática que quieres usar. Para evitarlo puedes usar math.h en lugar de cmath o escribir using namespace std;
Lo mismo sucede con otras librerías de C que tienen su contraparte de C++ como time.h y ctime, stdlib.h y cstdlib, etc.
